# VB.Net Split A Group Of Text

Tags: string, vb.net, split

I am looking to split up multiple lines of text to single them out, for example:

```
 Url/Host:ftp://server.com/1
 Login:Admin1 
 Password:Password1

 Url/Host:ftp://server.com/2
 Login:Admin2 
 Password:Password2

 Url/Host:ftp://server.com/3
 Login:Admin3 
 Password:Password3
```

How can I split each section into a different textbox, so that section one would be put into TextBox1.Text on its own:

```
 Url/Host:ftp://server.com/1
 Login:Admin1 
 Password:Password1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the exact format you could just split it on two newlines in a row:

```
Dim text As String ' your text
Dim sep() As String = {vbNewLine & vbNewLine}
Dim sections() As String = text.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

and then just loop through them and put one value in each Textbox.